# Shopping Cart Multiple atribute products

Tags: php, arrays, cart

I've create a solid multiple product shopping cart some long time ago, and now i've decided to add multiple attributes to products (such as size, color...).

My database is something like this:

Products:
id
...

attributes
id
name (color/size)
value (blue/grey/XXL)
...

Product_attributes
id
atribute_id
product_id

I've added the atribute inputs on single product page, in a such way (it's working)

```
if(the product has atributes on product_attributes table){
   while(there's product_attributes id){
        echo <select name=".$name.">
        while(there's atributes equal to product_attributes){
             echo <option value=".$id.">$value</option>
        }
        echo </select>
   }
}
<input type="number" name="qtd"> //quantity input
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="$product_id">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">
<input submit>
```

And on the cart.php, i've the following script

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'add'){
    $product= $_POST['product_id'];
    $qty= $_POST['qtd'];

    if(!empty($_SESSION['cart'][$product])){
        $qty= $qty+ $_SESSION['cart'][$product];

    }
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product] = $qty;
    header('location: cart');
}
```

how can i adapt this script to the new atribute input i have, knowing that:
not all products has atributes;
the product can have one or infinite atributes;
saving the product in different arrays due to qty of them and depending of his atributes (ex: Prod: 1, color: blue, Size: L Qty: 2 | Prod: 1, Color: Black, Size: l, Qty: 1)

Could anyone help me with this dilema?
I love your kindness ;)

Answer (score 1):

I give you only the idea create two tables :

one for attribute's type

**attribute**

id-name-value

1-size-42

2-taglia-xxl

then a table with the associations with the properties and the products

**associations**

id-product-attribute

autoincrement-1(for example id 1 product 1)- 2(attribute)

the product with that id has taglia xxl and if add any row will has other attributes

Answer (score 0):

### Create 3 tables

### 1)AttributeMaster

Id | AttributeName

### 2)AttributeValue

Id | AttId | Value

### 3)ProductAttribute

ID | PId |AttrId |AttvalueID

Comment: How this answer the question?